# Two activities sending data to each other

Tags: android

Two activities are sending data to each other.

The first activity has a custom list view. The second has one text view  and three buttons to increase and decrease a value.

When I click on the first activity, the second activity opens. The second activity increases the text view value and clicked the button. Data goes to the first activity. Same process again.

My problem is that the total value is not displayed in the first activity.

How can i show all increase and decrease values from the second activity in the first activity?

First activity's code:

```
package com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.bean.ListModel;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.json.JSONfunctions;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DetaisRESTActivity extends Activity {
    String messagevaluename,valueid,valueid1,valuename,pos;
    public String countString=null;
    String nameofsubmenu;
    public int count=0;
    public  String message=null;
    public  String message1=null;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView   listview;
    ArrayList aa;
    public  SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    public TextView   mTitleTextView;
    public   ImageButton imageButton;
    ListAdapterAddItems adapter;
    public TextView restaurantname = null;
    public TextView ruppees = null;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<ListModel> arraylist;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detais_rest);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));

        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("temp1", 1);



        //     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        int na=preferences.getInt("COUNTSTRING1",0);
        Log.i("asasassas",""+na);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textView123456789);

        imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,TotalPriceActivity.class);


                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    //    SqliteControllerSqliteController db = new SqliteControllerSqliteController(QuentityActivity.this);
        // Reading all contacts

   /*
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " +
                    cn.getPhoneNumber();
            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.d("Name: ", log);
        }

*/
















        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // get the extra value
        valuename = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenuname");
        valueid = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenunameid");
        valueid1 = intent.getStringExtra("idsrestaurantMenuId5");
        //totalamount = intent.getStringExtra("ruppees");
        Log.i("valueid",valueid);
        Log.i("valuename",valuename);
        Log.i("valueid1",valueid1);
       // Log.i("totalamount",totalamount);

        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }


    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetaisRESTActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(DetaisRESTActivity.this, "Successs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            //  Log.i("123",value1);
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://firstchoicefood.in/fcfapiphpexpert/phpexpert_restaurantMenuItem.php?r=" + URLEncoder.encode(valuename) + "&resid=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid1) + "&RestaurantCategoryID=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid) + "");



            try {

                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("RestaurantMenItems");
                Log.i("1234",""+jsonarray);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                     ListModel sched = new ListModel();
                    sched.setId(jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    sched.setProductName(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemName"));

                    sched.setPrice(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemPrice"));

                    arraylist.add(sched);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
      listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdetails);

            adapter = new ListAdapterAddItems();

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
                {

                    // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
                    ListModel p =(ListModel)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want
                    Log.i("SomeTag",""+p.getId());
                    //String itemvalue=(String)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.getProductName());
                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Ruppees: " + p.getPrice());

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Item " + (position + 1),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();

                       Log.i("postititi",""+position);

                    Intent intent=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,QuentityActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("quentity",countString);
                    intent.putExtra("valueid",valueid);
                    intent.putExtra("valuename",valuename);
                    intent.putExtra("valueid1",valueid1);
                    intent.putExtra("id",p.getId());
                    intent.putExtra("name",p.getProductName());
                    intent.putExtra("price",p.getPrice());
                    startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                   // startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
    }


    // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if(requestCode==2)
        {

            pos=data.getStringExtra("POSITION");
            message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            message1=data.getStringExtra("COUNTSTRING");
            messagevaluename=data.getStringExtra("VALUENAME");
            nameofsubmenu=data.getStringExtra("name");
            Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxx",message);
            Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxx1234",pos);
            Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxx5678count",message1);
            Log.i("messagevaluename",messagevaluename);
            Log.i("submenu",nameofsubmenu);
            //ruppees.setText(message);
            //editor.putInt("count",na);
            //editor.commit();
            //Log.i("asasassasasdsasdasd",""+na);

           //  mTitleTextView.setText(Arrays.toString(message1));
            mTitleTextView.setText(message1);

            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,TotalPriceActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("count",message1);

                    i.putExtra("submenu",nameofsubmenu);
                    i.putExtra("ruppees",message);
                    i.putExtra("id",pos);
                    i.putExtra("messagevaluename",messagevaluename);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });


        }
    }

    //==========================
    class ListAdapterAddItems extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel>
    {
        ListAdapterAddItems(){
            super(DetaisRESTActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
            //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlistitem, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(arraylist.get(position));

          //  arraylist.get(position).getPrice();
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {



        ViewHolder(View row) {
            restaurantname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamedetailsrestaurant);
            ruppees = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantcuisinedetalsrestaurant);

        }

        // Notice we have to change our populateFrom() to take an argument of type "Person"
        void populateFrom(ListModel r) {
            restaurantname.setText(r.getProductName());
            ruppees.setText(r.getPrice());

        }


    }














        //=============================================================






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detais_rest, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
public void OnPause(){
    super.onPause();


}
}
```

Second activity's code:

```
package com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.bean.CARTBean;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.bean.ListModel;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.database.SqliteController;


public class QuentityActivity extends Activity {
String value=null;
    public String TotAmt=null;
    String[] cccc;
    ImageButton positive,negative;
    String position;
    static int count = 1;
    int tot_amt = 0;
    public  String countString=null;
    String name,price;
    String valueid,valueid1,valuename;

    public TextView ruppees,submenuname,totalruppees,quantity,addtocart;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quentity);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("temp1",1);
      editor = preferences.edit();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // get the extra value
        value = intent.getStringExtra("quentity");
        valuename = intent.getStringExtra("valuename");
        valueid = intent.getStringExtra("valueid");
        valueid1 = intent.getStringExtra("valueid1");
        name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
        price=intent.getStringExtra("price");
        position=intent.getStringExtra("id");

        quantity=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantcuisinedetalsrestaurantquantity);
        totalruppees=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamequentitytotal1);
        submenuname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamesubmenuquentity);
        ruppees=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamequentity1);
        positive=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonpositive);
        negative=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonnegative);
        addtocart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewaddtocart);
        buttonclick();
        addtocart();


        submenuname.setText(name);
        ruppees.setText(price);
        totalruppees.setText(price);
        // new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }


    public void buttonclick(){
        positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {





                String totalAmtString = ruppees.getText().toString();
                int totAmount = Integer.parseInt(totalAmtString);
                //count = Integer.parseInt(getString);
                count++;

                editor.putInt("COUNTSTRING1", count);
                editor.commit();
                editor.clear();
                Log.i("sunder sharma",""+count);
                countString= String.valueOf(count);
                tot_amt = totAmount * count;

                TotAmt = String.valueOf(tot_amt);

                totalruppees.setText(TotAmt);
                quantity.setText(countString);

           }
        });


        negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String totalAmtString = ruppees.getText().toString();
                int totAmount = Integer.parseInt(totalAmtString);

                if (count > 1)
                    count--;
                editor.putInt("COUNTSTRING1", count);
                editor.commit();
                countString = String.valueOf(count);

                tot_amt = totAmount * count;

                TotAmt = String.valueOf(tot_amt);

                totalruppees.setText(TotAmt);
                quantity.setText(countString);

            }
        });

    }
    public void addtocart(){
        addtocart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

          /*      Log.i("valueid",valueid);
                Log.i("valuename",valuename);
                Log.i("valueid1",valueid1);
                Log.i("name",name);
                Log.i("price",price);
                Log.i("id1",position);
                SqliteController db = new SqliteController(QuentityActivity.this);
                db.insertStudent(new CARTBean(position,name,price,countString,TotAmt));


*/








                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",TotAmt);
                intent.putExtra("POSITION",position);
                intent.putExtra("COUNTSTRING",countString);

                intent.putExtra("VALUENAME",valuename);
                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                setResult(2,intent);
                finish();//finishing activity

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quentity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: wait 2 min i edited my question

Comment: Use intents to sends values across Activity, and make sure you update the GUI and code the GUI right in the first place. I need your code to give you further helps and debugging.

Comment: @sundersharma Ok. Just a note; Your code do A LOT more than what are you had first explained. If you could only put codes which significant to the cause, that will be nice.

Comment: @Isaac My first activity also have  custom action bar.Can  you solve my problem thanks in advance

Comment: @Isaac  you can also check my screen sort http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341896/i-want-this-like-screen-sort-i-want-to-action-bar-value-is-update-every-clicked

Comment: @sundersharma oh nice! maybe this link will help you [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Collect the data from second activity and put into below intent .Then you will receive first activity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(secondActivity.this, firstActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("COUNTSTRING", CountString);    //add data
startActivity(myIntent);
```